# Are there any websites like alltop that are political in nature?

Tags: web, hyperlink

I am looking for a link agitator like popurls or alttop but for political news. Does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://lvrnews.com. It has a couple hundred websites broken down by Democrat / Progressive & Conservative / Republican news sources.